# Drupal broken site after settings.php change

Tags: php, drupal, settings

While I was working on a drupal site I encountered a critical error, I tried to edit settings.php file (for changing database credentials) but when I saved the file (I use register.it control panel) i received an XMLRPC fault error, now when I browse my site it shows installation page and nothing else.
Do some of you know what happened and how to restore it?
I tried to rename the file default.settings.php but it says that there is already a settings.php file (that I can't see anyway )

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Might be the best place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see installation page that means that Drupal is not aware of existing database (can't connect to it) so it want to start new installation - setup new database.

So if database is ok problem must be in your settings file: bad credentials (i.e. maybe you can't use "localhost" for host but something host company provided) or file it self is not accessible (insufficient permissions?)

Comment: That was the problem!
I was doing all of this to restrict access to a previous admin that is doing some mess, I found that he commented the valid credentials and uncommented the default ones.

Comment: It my answer solved your problem please mark it that way.